# A project with an Output type of Class Library cannot be started directly ERROR

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

When i finished the object oriented design for my project "monopoly", i implemented some simple buttons on the board (as u can see in the background) and made a simple function to them just to test my project how its going..anyway i cant run my project, it  shows me this error message 
And i tried the set as a startup project method for my project but it didnt work... 
any help plz?
[image]
A project with an output type of class library cannot be started directly.In order to debug this project, add an executable project to this solution which references the library project. Set the executable project as the startup project.

```
 A project with an output type of class library cannot be started directly.In order to debug this project, add an executable project to this solution which references the library project. Set the executable project as the startup project.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've accidentally created the project as a class library instead of a Windows application.  To rectify:

1. Right click the project in *Solution Explorer* on the right
2. Click *Properties*
3. Select the *Application* tab (should be the top one)
4. Change Output type to *Windows Application*
5. Save
6. Try to compile again

Comment: This fix my issue, thank you!